# I need to know what is triggering the Excel "Do you want to save ..." dialogue

Tags: excel

I open a certain Excel 2007 workbook then close it without making any manual changes but I get the "Do you want to save ... ?" dialogue presumably because something within in it is auto-calculating.  I put Msgbox(ThisWorkBook.Saved) during the WorkBook Open event and it shows False which indeed suggests that something somewhere is changing immediately but I've put WorksheetChange event code on each of the worksheets and none of them are triggered.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Any in-cell volatile function will cause this behaviour.  This includes things like `RAND()`, `TODAY()` etc., as well as any user defined functions that have been declared as volatile, i.e. have the declaration `Application.Volatile`.

Further reading http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm

Comment: Should they not trigger the WorksheetChange event code ? I've eyeballed all the cells several times and although they contain some fairly heavy formulae I can't see anything volatile.